# Android - ListView within a ListView does not expand to show all items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a listview of items that have a listview as a child.  My problem is that the child listview does not expand to show all items.

Parent layout

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="0px"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/site_wallet_header"
        style="@style/Home.ListHeader" />

    <ListView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/site_wallet_list" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Child layout

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/ListItem"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bank_icon"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/bank_name"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        style="@style/ListItem.Text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Parent collection `ArrayAdapter`

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(resourceId, null);
    }

    AccountSummary account = accounts.get(position);

    if (account != null) 
    {
        TextView header = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.site_wallet_header);
        header.setText(account.Name);

        if (account.Banks.length == 0) {
            //LinearLayout noBanks = (LinearLayout) context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.no_banks, null);
        } else {
            ListView banksList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.site_wallet_list);
            //banksList.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

            banksList.clearChoices();
            banksList.setAdapter(new BankSummaryAdapter(context, R.layout.list_item_bank, account.Banks));
        }
    }

    return v;
}
```

Child collection `ArrayAdapter`

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(resourceId, null);
    }

    BankSummary bank = items.get(position);

    if (bank != null) 
    {
        TextView nameText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bank_name);
        ImageView iconImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.bank_icon);

        nameText.setText(bank.DisplayName);

        Resources res = context.getResources();


        switch (bank.BankCode)
        {
            case 'V':
                iconImage.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_visa));
                break;
            case 'M':
                iconImage.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_mastercard));
                break;
            case 'D':
                iconImage.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_discover));
                break;
            case 'A':
                iconImage.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_american_express));
                break;
            default:
                iconImage.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_echeck));
                break;
        }
    }

    return v;
}
```

Here is what it is doing.

[image: frustration]

My goal here is to have these header lists that are loaded dynamically.  This screen will be scrollable with the child lists always showing every item.  No matter what I try, however, I can't seem to get the child list to expand completely.  I really want to avoid building the entire thing in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you will have much better luck by using an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) and an [ExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html) instead of this complicated layout.

You can then expand every group by iterating through them and calling `expandGroup(int groupPos)`

Comment: Works like a champ.  Thank you!